# Deleting NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to make an application where a user can edit attributes of a `managedObject` in a view, and select either `Done` to persist the changes, or `Cancel` to undo the changes.

To implement this behavior, I plan to do the following-

- When the view controller is loaded to edit the `managedObject`, create a `backupManagedObject` which is a clone of the original `managedObject`.
- This `backupManagedObject` is created in a separate **child ManagedObjectContext**.
- Let the user edit the original `managedObject`.
- If:

  - `Done` is pressed, the original `managedObject` is persisted, and backup is deleted
  - `Cancel` is pressed, the `backupManagedObject` is cloned into original `managedObject` and the backup is deleted

My question is, once I am done with the `backupManagedObject`, how can I delete the `childManagedObjectContext` which will have no more managed objects and I don't plan to use them anymore (for every new view controller, I plan to just create a new child managed object context and destroy it once view controller is done).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a managed object context is release the same way any other object in Objective-C is released and deallocated.

If you are using ARC, simply set the property to `nil` when you no longer need it and it will be destroyed along with any unsaved changes.

However, your approach for this problem is a bit complicated.
You could simply create a new "editing" child context, fetch the objects you like to edit in that context and make changes to the objects.

If the user decide to commit the changes, save the context (up to the store), and if not, simply destroy the context.

Comment: How can I destroy the context if I am using ARC. If I just set the `managedObject.managedObjectContext = nil`, it gets deallocated?

Comment: I am unable to set managedObject's `managedObjectContext` since it gives the error: `No setter method setManagedObjectContext: for assignment to property`

Comment: a managed object expose its context as a read-only property (you cannot assign it directly). the managed object hold the context as a weak reference so there is no need to nullify this property for the object. you should only nullify properties you created as strong references to your "editing" context, when the last one is nullified the context will be released.

Answer (score 7):

You should do this the other way around:

When you load your editing View Controller, create new **Managed Object Context** that is the child of your main one, let's call it the *editingMOC*.

Do the edits to the *editingMOC*, and if you want to persist them, save the *editingMOC* (this will propagate changes to the *mainMOC*), and then save the *mainMOC* to save the data to the persistent store.

If you wish to discard the changes done to the *editingMOC*, simply do not save them and let the context get dealloc'd.

Comment: Got it, so you mean when loading the editing view controller, use `existingObjectWithID:error:` to copy the object from *mainMOC* to *editingMOC*? So if there are any relationships that are created or deleted, does that get committed too?

Comment: Yep, every change will get saved.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to simply create the view and populate the UI controls (text fields, etc.) using data from the NSManagedObject attributes.  If the user makes any edits then set a flag so you know if changes are made and then when they select Done update the NSManagedObject attributes using values from the UI controls and save the MOC.  If they select Cancel then don't do anything.

See this link for a video showing an app using a similar approach for editing Core Data records on iOS. The OSX app uses standard NSPersistentDocument undo manager.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/os-x-and-ios-app-integration-with-core-data-and-icloud/